# Añadir valor en Object

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de añadir un valor al objeto, intenté usando `foreach` dentro de otro `foreach`, pero no tuve éxito.

Array original:

```js
[
      {
        "valor 1": "Estado 1",
        "preguntas": [
          {
            "pregunta_id": 1,
            "pregunta": "Pregunta 1",
          },
          {
            "pregunta_id": 2,
            "pregunta": "Pregunta 2",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "valor 1": "Estado 2",
        "preguntas": [
          {
            "pregunta_id": 3,
            "pregunta": "Pregunta 1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Resultado esperado:

Lo que intento es añadir el key resultado con el valor por defecto 0.

```js
    [
      {
        "valor 1": "Estado 1",
        "preguntas": [
          {
            "pregunta_id": 1,
            "pregunta": "Pregunta 1",
            "resultado": 0
          },
          {
            "pregunta_id": 2,
            "pregunta": "Pregunta 2",
            "resultado": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "valor 1": "Estado 2",
        "preguntas": [
          {
            "pregunta_id": 3,
            "pregunta": "Pregunta 1",
            "resultado": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Intenté también usar map, pero tampoco tuve resultados esperados.

> (Texto de relleno motivo: Parece que tu publicación es mayormente
>   código; por favor, añade más detalles.)

Comment: ¿Quieres añadirle ese campo a cada objeto pregunta o a alguno en específico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres convertir el array de objetos original puedes usar un `map` dentro de un `map`, o un `forEach` y dentro del `forEach` un `map` de la siguiente manera:

```js
const orgObj = 
[
  {
    "valor 1": "Estado 1",
    "preguntas": [
      {
        "pregunta_id": 1,
        "pregunta": "Pregunta 1",
      },
      {
        "pregunta_id": 2,
        "pregunta": "Pregunta 2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "valor 1": "Estado 2",
    "preguntas": [
      {
        "pregunta_id": 3,
        "pregunta": "Pregunta 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]

orgObj.forEach(el =>{
   el.preguntas = el.preguntas.map(obj => {obj.resultado = 0; return obj});
});

console.log(orgObj);
```

En resumen, modificamos cada objeto que contenga la propiedad preguntas para añadirle a este una propiedad resultado con un valor inicial de `0`.

Ten en cuenta que esto modificaría también el objeto original, en caso de que no quieras este comportamiento entonces deberas hacer una copia primero del objeto en cuestion usando `Object.assign`.

Comment: Simple y claro! +1

Comment: Acabo de leer el último comentario ed tu respuesta... Parece que te has adelantado, como siempre. +1

Answer (score 2):

La solución de usar `map` está bien. En este caso se tendrán que usar dos `map` anidados.
Veo que @Riven ya ha dado con la solución, voy a proponer la forma funcional. No es ni mejor ni peor, es sólo otro paradigma.

Siendo `v` tu objeto.

```
const addKeyValue = (key, value) =>
    // Mapeamos el array de objetos
    v.map(obj => {
        const { preguntas } = obj;
        // Mapeamos el array de preguntas.
        obj.preguntas = preguntas.map(p => {
            // Hacemos un spread del objeto
            // y le añadimos el campo adicional
            return {
                ...p,
                [key]: value
            };
        });

        return obj;
    });
```

Con el paradigma de la programación funcional, `addKeyValue` no modifica el objeto original, solo crea una copia modificada del mismo.

En tu caso, se usaría de la siguiente forma.

```
const newArr = addKeyValue('resultado', 0);
```

Espero que sirva.